# .htacess adding pagination to the a file S_NSW.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

currently in the directory `example.com.au/directory1/nsw/` I have below `.htaccess`

```
   RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ S_NSW.php?p=$1
       RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ S_NSW.php?p=$1
```

the filename is `S_NSW.php`
current `.htaccess` is

In order to make the url look like

```
example.com.au/directory1/suburb-nsw
```

the above code works, however I need extra by adding pagination and make the url look like

> example.com.au/directory1/suburb-nsw/1/
>
> example.com.au/directory1/suburb-nsw/2/
>
> example.com.au/directory1/suburb-nsw/3/

Comment: What is the rewrite condition? What is the 'before' URL that you're trying to rewrite? What have you tried already?If you want help you need to share a lot more so that people can debug the situation for you.

Comment: the server structure is: /public_html/example.com.au/directory1/nsw/

Comment: I'm trying to generate pagination so it looks like: example.com.au/directory1/suburb-nsw/1/,  currently  doesnt work for pagination it only works for the firs page: example.com.au/directory1/suburb-nsw ,   I do have  have a pagination that works on  but with index.php in the directory , example.com.au/directory1/Sydney/1/, with the following code on the folder: RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ index.php?pi=$1 [NC,L], however when I changed it to RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ S_NSW.php?pi=$1 [NC,L], still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, too easy.
by adding the following line into the root .htaccss file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$3/S_NSW.php?p=$2&pi=$4 [L,NC,QSA,NE]
```

also by adding the following code into example.com.au/directory1/suburb-nsw

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ S_NSW.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ S_NSW.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ S_NSW.php?p=$1&pi=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^nsw/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ S_NSW.php?p=$1&pi=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-^nsw/([0-9]+)/$ S_NSW.php?p=$1&pi=$2 [NC,L]
```